# SQL Query fails when content of a single parameter change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query

Im very puzzled about this issue.. I have a SQL Server database with many records and it is used by my website. When the website user searches for a specific record, the SQL command gets a timeout. The only thing that is different between searches is the parameter.
Everything works within SQL Management Studio. Using newest version of SQL Server Express on a Windows Server 2016.

This fails with a timeout:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM dbo.v_MyView WHERE 1=@ONE AND Name LIKE @name Order by dbo.v_MyView.Date Desc OFFSET (0) ROWS FETCH NEXT (10) ROWS ONLY
Parameters: @ONE 1, @name flop%
```

This works:

```
Query: SELECT * FROM dbo.v_MyView WHERE 1=@ONE AND Name LIKE @name Order by dbo.v_MyView.Date Desc OFFSET (0) ROWS FETCH NEXT (10) ROWS ONLY
Parameters: @ONE 1, @name bandit%
```

Notice that it is only the content of the parameter @name that changes. searching for "flop%" fails and searching for "bandit%" works.

Comment: This might be due to parameter sniffing. [This article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) is worth a read. Possible solutions are to add a query hint, such as `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION(OPTIMIZED FOR UNKNOWN)` as detailed more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432794/what-are-the-main-differences-between-optionoptimize-for-unknown-and-optionre).

Comment: Thanks! Im pretty sure I already tried the OPTION(RECOMPILE) some time earlier when the issue first occured... But just tried it again and now it seems to be working. I will have to wait until monday when users are online again before I can fully verify that the fix worked.

Comment: It may be statistics need to be updated If recompile didn't help. Good row count estimates are key so that SQL Server can generate an optimal plan.

Comment: Yeah maybe I should look into statistics. Just checked and the statistics have not been update for 2 months. Around the time when the db got detatched and moved to a new SQL Server. Only the indexes have recently been updated.

Comment: Are you able to paste the execution plan and share it with us? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/